# ffmpeg image creation

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg, thumbnails

im using ffmpeg in my server and every thing is working fine except one that the image(thumbnail) creation im using this script

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/test/test.flv -deinterlace -an -ss 13.45 
                -t 00:00:05 -r 0.01 -y -s 120x72 -vcodec mjpeg 
                -f mjpeg /var/www/test/test.jpg
```

is there any problem with the PHP or ffmpeg

Thanks

Comment: Posting the error message is *probably* the only way we are going to be able to help you.  That or the test.flv itself.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some playing with this on my own FLV files and found that the r value (frame rate) you have there is probably too small, at least it was for the FLV I tested on.

Change it to something like .1 or maybe even 1

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /var/www/test/test.flv -deinterlace -an -ss 13.45 
                -t 00:00:05 -r 1 -y -s 120x72 -vcodec mjpeg 
                -f mjpeg /var/www/test/test.jpg
```